# Why am I not able to exclude __pycache__ directory with .gitignore?

Tags: python, git, gitignore

I'm trying to exclude the pycache directory with these lines:

```
aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/
*.pyc
```

I can list that directory from my current location:

```
ls .\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\__pycache__\

    Directory: C:\Users\bluet\OneDrive\Desktop\important_folders\Jokefire\git\jf_cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\__pycache__

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM            763 aws_add_sg_list.cpython-39.pyc
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM           1173 aws_tag_resources.cpython-39.pyc
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM            894 banners.cpython-39.pyc
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM           1148 choose_accounts.cpython-39.pyc
la---            5/4/2021  8:10 AM          12871 ec2_mongo.cpython-38.pyc
la---           5/15/2021 10:01 AM          15714 ec2_mongo.cpython-39.pyc
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM            811 find_vpcs.cpython-39.pyc
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM           1183 init.cpython-39.pyc
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM            848 list_new_instances.cpython-39.pyc 
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM            937 modules.cpython-39.pyc
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM            665 read_account_info.cpython-39.pyc  
la---           5/16/2021 10:47 PM           6764 user_input.cpython-39.pyc
```

Yet, when I do a git status it still shows me the `__pycache__` directory:

```
git status        
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/.gitignore

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/ec2_mongo.cpython-39.pyc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your .gitignore file `__pycache__/`

EDIT:

It is because you have already added it to the staging area.  Try this:

`git rm --cached -r __pycache__`

Comment: I tried that too. This is my entire `.gitignore` file:
```*.pyc
__pycache__/
.vscode/
aws_scripts/output_files/
aws_scripts/source_files/```

Comment: Yet when do a git status the `__pycache__` directory is still there:
```git status
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/ec2_mongo.cpython-39.pyc```

Comment: I have made the edit. It should work now